# Create one script that runs all others with single path?

Tags: python, command-line, path

I have made about 15 python scripts, that runs from command line and a second after running any of that scripts, I need to enter a path, which is xml file(I made a python script that compares value of tags from different XML classes). But it's getting boring to runs all scripts one by one... so, what is the best way to create one script that will run all other with the single path? 
Output of script is excel file, so I need 15 excel file, each for every script.

Comment: do it with shell scrpting or batch if you are on windows

Comment: No, I'm using mac.

Comment: Then use shell scripting (or applescript, I suppose).

Comment: The `Pythonic` way is to import all 15 `script's` into **one** `script` and start this.